# Prefill Signers detail SignRequest

Tags: apex, visualforce, appexchange

I'm trying to send some documents to the customer using the SignRequest app exchange product.
I need to automatically prefill the signer's details when SignRequest is invoked from the salesforce.

I have followed all the steps given [here](https://help.signrequest.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000453133-Prefill-signers-in-Salesforce-Classic-Lightning-), but in inspect element, I'm seeing below error:

> TypeError: e.prefilled_signers.forEach is not a function

Here is my code which I’ve tried as of now:

```
window.SR_SETTINGS = {
      objectId: '{!Contact.Id}',
      objectType: 'Contact',
      popupWidth: 600,
      srDomain: '',
      organizationId: '{!$Organization.Id}',
      userId: '{!$User.Id}',
      profileId: '{!$User.ProfileId}',
      close: true,
      accountApiName: '',
      contactApiName: '',
      msg: `This is a demo message.`,
      prefilled_signers: [{
        email:"{!Contact.Email}",
        order:0,
        level:'signature'
    }]
    };
```

Comment: The link "here" in your question is broken

Comment: @rahulgawale I have added the link

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the SignRequest app is not able to properly read values from prefilled_signers.

If you need to send a single signer detail, see if it works if you try to send an object directly, without the array annotation.

```
window.SR_SETTINGS = {
      objectId: '{!Contact.Id}',
      objectType: 'Contact',
      popupWidth: 600,
      srDomain: '',
      organizationId: '{!$Organization.Id}',
      userId: '{!$User.Id}',
      profileId: '{!$User.ProfileId}',
      close: true,
      accountApiName: '',
      contactApiName: '',
      msg: `This is a demo message.`,
      prefilled_signers: {
        email:"{!Contact.Email}",
        order:0,
        level:'signature'
    }
   };
```

Comment: Even it doesn't work with single signer detail